# Scroll event doesn't trigger

Tags: aurelia

I have a problem with **scroll** binding. I tried to use [scroll binding](https://www.danyow.net/scroll-binding-with-aurelia/) and [event listeners](http://ilikekillnerds.com/2016/02/using-event-listeners-in-aurelia/)  without luck. Using jquery doesn't work either. Any other event I tried works as expected, but with **scroll** it does literally nothing. No error, no message .. What am I missing?

#### Edit

Ok I made a mistake and didn't put it in the app.js and app.html as mentioned in examples but one layer under so there was no scroll event to catch on the element. If I put scroll.trigger there it works.

**New question:**
Can scroll be triggered in children views?

Eg.: lets say you have 2 view-models on 2 routes and you want one to trigger scroll event and the other not to. Can someone point me to right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Can check this ? [website for detail](https://gist.run/?id=f5b43de0086cddc254ce)

Comment: That is the example by Jeremy Danyow I mentioned. It doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found mistake causing my original problem - it is described in question.

To answer my second question I used this solution:

**app.html**

```
<div class="page-host" scroll.trigger="handleScrollEvent($event) & debounce:200">
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
export class App {

  configureRouter(config, router) {
    config.title = 'Title';

    config.map([
      { route: ['', 'first'], name: 'first', moduleId: './first', nav: true, title: 'First route' },
      { route: ['second'], name: 'second', moduleId: './second', nav: true, title: 'Second route' }
    ]);

    this.router = router;
  }

  handleScrollEvent(e) {

    // if not on specified route
    if(this.router.currentInstruction.config.name !== 'second') {
      return;
    }

    // if scrolled under defined pixels
    if(e.target.scrollTop > 100) {
      $('body').find('#toolbar').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
      $('body').find('#toolbar').removeClass('fixed');
    }

  }

}
```

I don't know how clean it is but it is working. Feel free to sugest other solution.